# Why is "keys" not defined in the code, but is on the console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following code which parses a JSON string into some variables:

```
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  vm[keys(data)[0]] = values(data)[0];
}
```

The incoming string will always be in the form of

```
{
  "somename": something
}
```

`something` can be a value or an Array.

My intent was to get the first (and only) key and the first (and only) value and use them to update another variable (`vm`).

When debugging the code in Chrome Developer Tools, it stops at `keys`:

```
infoscreen.js:33 Uncaught ReferenceError: keys is not defined
    at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (infoscreen.js:33)
ws.onmessage @ infoscreen.js:33
```

On the same console I have, however,

```
> keys(data)[0]
< "calendar"
```

**Why is `keys` undefined at run time but is available (and returns the expected result) on the console?**

Comment: Try using `Object.keys(data)`

Comment: Is it running in a web worker? E.g., does `self.keys` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome dev tools is a command line that can provide a simple javascript-access, but also gives contains a collection of convenience functions for performing common tasks.

The [`keys` function](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#keysobject) is one of them (which gives the same output as [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)), but there are also multiple functions you can use.

In your code you should use `Object.keys` instead:

```
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  vm[Object.keys(data)[0]] = values(data)[0];
}
```

Here is the complete command line reference:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference

And this is the reference to the Object.keys function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: I would add the [Object.keys reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) too

Comment: @Eineki, it's already there (link on `Object.keys`, second paragraph)

Comment: my fault, I was distracted by the reference at the end of your answer and missed the link in its body

Comment: I guess it's worth adding in the end :) check the udpate